# How to pragmatically connect signal to slot within ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I created a segment control in a custom `UIView`, now I need to change the `UIView's` color if the segment control changes.

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.circleColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        self.segmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems: @[@"Red", @"Green", @"Blue"]];
        CGRect f = self.segmentControl.frame;
        f.origin = CGPointMake(0, [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height);
        self.segmentControl.frame = f;
        [self addSubview:self.segmentControl];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I thought there is something like `self.segmentControl setCallbackForEvent:(UIEvent*)event:(Callback)action`, but I could not manage to find such method in `UIView`.

So I tried the following code, but would not work either:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    NSSet<UITouch*>* segTouches = [event touchesForView:self.segmentControl];
    if (segTouches.count != 0 && self.segmentControl.selected) {
        UIColor* color = nil;
        switch (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            case 0:
                color = [UIColor redColor];
                break;
            case 1:
                color = [UIColor greenColor];
                break;
            case 2:
                color = [UIColor blueColor];
                break;
            default:
                assert(0);
                break;

        }
        self.circleColor = color;
    }
}
```

How could I progmatically connect the signal(segment control value changed) to slot(change to color of view) progmatically without interface builder in ios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple Docs on segmented controls

> You register the target-action methods for a segmented control using the UIControlEventValueChanged constant as shown below.

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(changeColor:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

You could then create a changeColor: function and put the color changing code in there.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out how to use `UISegmentedControl`on the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UISegmentedControl).